# Resistors for a Solid State Relay

Tags: relay, dc, automotive

I have a controller output fused at 250 mA, and I need to use that output to switch a 1.5 A load. Everything is 12 VDC in the vehicle. Figured I'd be using a solid state relay.

Do I need to be worried about blowing that fuse if I tie the SSR into the controller output without a resistor?

Comment: *That* fuse and *that* SSR and *a* controller? Show your wiring diagram and [edit] your post to include datasheet links (no Amazon ad links) to the SSR and the controller.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the SSR. Typically the input to the SSR is an LED, it may have an internal resistor, it may have current limiting, it may have other protections such as reverse polarity, or it may just be a bare LED and you will have to provide the current limiting yourself.

You'll need to look for one that will not only handle the load but also be compatible with your controller. The datasheets should tell you all you need to know.